# How to get better series expansion of expressions involving exponential

Tags: series-expansion

I tried to compute the series expansion of this equation

```
r1 = 1/2 (1 + 2^(-1 - k) (1 + (3/5)^(1 + k))^(1 + k))
Series[r1, {k, Infinity, 1}] // Normal // Expand
```

which gives ouput

```
1/2 + 2^(-2 - k) (1 + (5/3)^(-1 - k))^k +  3/20 (1 + (5/3)^(-1 - k))^k E^(k (-Log[5/3] - Log[2]))
```

This is not particularly useful. A clearer result would be

```
1/2 + 1/2^(k+2) + O(k/2^(2 k)),
```

which can be verified either manually or using Maple.
Is there a better way to do this type of series expansion in Mathematica?

Comment: What version are you using? When I run your code, it basically spits back the original function without doing any expansion.

Comment: I use version  Mathematica 11.3 and Maple 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you transform your equation to

```
2 r1-1==1/2^(k + 1) (1 + (3/5)^(k + 1))^(k + 1)
```

and use the binomial expansion for the last term you'll get

```
2 r1-1~ 1/2^(k + 1)(1+3/5(k+1)+1/2 (3/5)^2 k(k+1)+O[k^3])
```

That's the expansion you found!